# How to mark specific frames in a video stream/insert frame metadata to later recognize it on the receiving side

Tags: video, encoding, data-synchronization

Sorry for a rather complicated question topic.
I describe here the endgoal just to clarify why marking video frames.

I need to overlay infographic effects on a video stream which is received from the internet/satellite (h264). The effects should be synced to video frames so that they appear natural. The main problem is that the infographics are context depended, they are different for each receiving client. So it is impossible to overlay them at the stream source and stream in with infographics already embedded.

The idea I came up with is to insert myself into video encoding chain, mark specific frames with synch data (how?) and decode this on the receiving side.

To be more specific = the markers should look like "tag1" "tag2" "tag3", and the receiving party with show its infographic for tag1, tag2, tag3.

The problem is, this is not a standard task, to insert metadata into frames (i know ffmpeg does this, but for the whole media file).
The next problem is that the stream is not a media file, rather it is live from a camera, so that it cannot be preprocessed and saved.

Do you have an idea where to start, or an idea how this task could be accomplished without messing with the encoding pipeline?